# Test Match abandon Conditions?

Tags: rules, cricket

How many Overs (minimum) are required to have a result (draw or win) in a test match so that match abandon law doesn't apply?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None. In general, an abandonment is not a result which is covered by the [Laws of Cricket](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/); an abandonment can happen only if an agreement is made under Law 13.1.2 ("Number of innings") as referred to by [Law 16.4](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-16-the-result/):

> **Matches in which there is an agreement under Law 13.1.2**
>
> For any match in which there is an agreement under Law 13.1.2 (Number of innings), if the result is not determined in any of the ways stated in 16.1, 16.2 or 16.3, then the result shall be as laid down in that agreement.

The [Test Match Playing Conditions](https://pulse-static-files.s3.amazonaws.com/ICC/document/2017/10/05/226f919d-1bdd-4719-a32b-11b582a1c8a0/ICC-Men-s-Test-Match-Playing-Conditions-2017-Code-FINAL-051017.pdf) do not contain any such agreement under Law 13.1.2, so an abandonment is not a possible result of a Test Match. (The ODI and T20 playing conditions do contain such an agreement, so an abandonment is possible there).

One case in which a Test Match could (in theory) result in a win without a ball being bowled would be if one side refused to take the field; the umpires would then award the match to the other side in accordance with Law 16.3.1:

> a match shall be lost by a side which
>
> [...]
>
> in the opinion of the umpires refuses to play.  If so, the umpires shall award the match to the other side.

Comment: so in that case if a test match with only one over bowled will be considerd to be drawn?

Comment: @EdwinThomas Yes, unless some suitable authority eventually decides to treat the match as never having happened (the laws only govern how the match proceeds, not how statisticians or contracts deal with the outcome).